# Regular Expression for matching a string that has numbers seperated by underscore and then see if any of those numbers are within particular ranges

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I need to create an oracle sql logic that evaluates a string that has numbers separated by underscores and need to find out if those numbers falls within a range.

I have a string that says 1_2_5_11_23_48_55_67_98 or any string that contains numbers separated by underscores and the numbers will be between 1 to 99.

The oracle sql logic needs to evaluate this string and sees if:

- If the string contains number  = ‘1’
  and any other number  between  ‘50’ & ‘99’
  and  does not contain any numbers  between values ‘2’ & ‘49’,
  then return the string with '_'  replaced by '|'.
- If the string contains number  = ‘1’
  and any other number between ‘2’ & ‘49’
  and optionally if there are any other numbers between ‘50’ & ‘99’),
  then return the modified string by removing the '1' and with '_' replaced by '|'.
- If string does not contain number  = ‘1’ but has other numbers, then return the string with '_' replaced by '|'.

if this can be done entirely using string manipulation, that would be fine too. otherwise, a solution using regular expression would be needed too.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you always need to replace `_` with `|`, and remove 1 if it is present. What problems do you have to do so?

Comment: @markalex as far as I understood it, the 1 is only removed if a number between 2 and 49 is present too

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, right, thank you. Misread the task.

Comment: This is not a coding service. People will help you when you include what you've done, and explain what is you were not able to do.

Comment: is the input ordered or could the numbers in that string be in any order?

Comment: it would be useful if you explain when '_' should not be replaced by '|'

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears to be able to be simplified to :

- If the string contains 1 and at least one number in the range from 2 to 49 then remove the 1 from the string.
- Then, for all strings, replace all underscores characters with pipe characters.

Which, can be implemented as:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REPLACE(
         CASE
         WHEN '_' || value || '_' LIKE '%_1_%'                -- Contains 1
         AND  REGEXP_LIKE(value, '(^|_)([2-9]|[1-4]\d)($|_)') -- Contains 2-49
         THEN TRIM(
                BOTH '_' FROM 
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                    '_' || REPLACE(value, '_', '__') || '_',
                    '_1_'
                  ),
                  '__',
                  '_'
                )
              )
         ELSE value
         END,
         '_',
         '|'
       ) AS updated_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '1_2_5_11_23_48_55_67_98' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2_49_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '99_1_50' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2_3_49' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '51_51_98_99_97' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '99_2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1_2_5_11_23_48_55_67_98 | 2|5|11|23|48|55|67|98 |
| 2_49_1 | 2|49 |
| 99_1_50 | 99|1|50 |
| 2_3_49 | 2|3|49 |
| 51_51_98_99_97 | 51|51|98|99|97 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 99_2 | 99|2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ABLKjxgZ)